# blocking some email extensions firebase

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication in my app. My mail verification feature is active. Some users use one-time mail verification extensions and open an account. They are doing this for abuse of the app. How can I prevent "nezid.com , xcoxc.com , jeoce.com , cdfaq.com " from registering with these mail extensions?

Signup code :

```
private void registeruser(){

        String email = editextregistermail.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()){
            kayıtemail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            kayıtemail.requestFocus();
            return;

        }

    

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,passworld).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                                                                    @Override
                                                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                                                                                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                                                            User user = new User(
                                                                                                    name,
                                                                                            );
                                                                                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                                                                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                                                                                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                                                @Override
                                                                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                                                   

                                                                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                                                                        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                                                                                                        if (user != null){
                                                                                                            user.sendEmailVerification()
                                                                                                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                                                                        @Override
                                                                                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                                                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                                                                                 Intent intent = new Intent(context, Login.class);
                                                                                                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                                                                                                finish();
                                                                                                                                mAuth.signOut();
                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                            else {
                                                                                                                                String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                                                                                                                                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                                                                                                mAuth.signOut();
                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                    });
                                                                                                        }





        );

       

    }
```

xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


                <EditText
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/signupmail"
                    android:id="@+id/editextregistermail"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:ems="14"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:background="@drawable/signup_edittext_style"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I prevent "nezid.com , xcoxc.com , jeoce.com , cdfaq.com "
> from registering with these mail extensions?

You can take advantage of the newly available [blocking Cloud Functions for Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions).

The doc shows an [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions#only_allowing_registration_from_a_specific_domain) which shows how to prevent users who aren't part of the `example.com` domain from registering with your app. You can easily adapt it to fulfill your need, as follows *(untested)*:

```
exports.beforeCreate = functions.auth.user().beforeCreate((user, context) => {

  const arrayOfDomains = ['nezid.com' , 'xcoxc.com' , 'jeoce.com' , 'cdfaq.com'];

  if (!user.email || arrayOfDomains.find(d => (user.email === d))) {
    throw new functions.auth.HttpsError(
      'invalid-argument', `Unauthorized email "${user.email}"`);
  }
});
```

---

Don't forget that you need to upgrade your Firebase project to Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform for this Cloud Function to work.

Comment: Thank you.  
But my coding knowledge is not that good at the moment. Instead I did : " 
 if (email.contains("nezid.com") || email.contains("cdfaq.com") || email.contains("jeoce.com") {
 editextregistermail.setError("...com mail extension is not valid");
            editextregistermail.requestFocus();
            return;   } "                                                                                                                                        Is there any problem with this method?

Comment: I understand that the code in your comment replaces the one in the `if` block in my answer. If this is the case then it is correct.